# Return array with HTML string to jquery $.post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am calling a php script with jquery $.post method as

```
$.post('{$site_url}tests/tests/content', params, function (data)
{
  $('#some-div1').html(data[1]);
  $('#some-div2').html(data[2]);
}
```

in php script I am returning following array as:

```
$return_html = array();
$return_html['key1'] = '<tr><td colspan="20" class="center">record 1</td></tr><tr><td colspan="20" class="center">record 2</td></tr>';

$return_html['key2'] = '<tr><td colspan="20" class="center">category 1</td></tr><tr><td colspan="20" class="center">category 2</td></tr>';

echo json_encode($return_html);
exit;
```

The return json string is not properly showing html on my page. How can I parse back it to valid html on html page

Comment: instead of data[1] and data[2] use data.key1 and data.key2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse the JSON array in your javascript in order to get the values contained within. I would recommend trying this out:

```
$.post('{$site_url}tests/tests/content', params, function (data)
{
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(parsedData);
}
```

This will put the data object into the console for you to see how it's composed. You should be able to access your returned data with parsedData.key1 and parsedData.key2.

Cheers!